# Closing & reopening window leaks memory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks

Got a problem here.  I'm creating a `MAAttachedWindow`, then hiding it when a certain event happens.  Here's how the code looks:

```
-(void)toggleDetailShouldShow:(BOOL)show {
    if (show) {
        if (!attachedWindow) {
            NSPoint buttonPoint = NSMakePoint(NSMidX([[someView someImageView] frame]),
                                              NSMidY([[someView someImageView] frame]));
            attachedWindow = [[MAAttachedWindow alloc] initWithView:view 
                                                    attachedToPoint:buttonPoint 
                                                           inWindow:window 
                                                             onSide:12
                                                         atDistance:65.0];
            //setup here
            [attachedWindow setAlphaValue:0.0];
            [[[someView someImageView] window] addChildWindow:attachedWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
            [[attachedWindow animator] setAlphaValue:1.0];
        } 
    }
    else {
        if (attachedWindow) {
            [[[someView someImageView] window] removeChildWindow:attachedWindow];
            [attachedWindow orderOut:self];
            [attachedWindow release];
            attachedWindow = nil;            
        }
    }
}
```

When this is triggered multiple times, my memory usage climbs steadily.  Any reason why this is leaking?

Comment: What specifically is leaking? The MAAttachedWindow?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm guessing.  Instruments doesn't show a leak at all, and that's where I'm running into a snag.  This is the only code that I triggered when the memory kept increasing.  That's why I figured it was this window that was leaking.

Comment: Only semi-related, but might I suggest my SFBPopoverWindow class- https://github.com/sbooth/SFBPopovers - it is similar to MAAttachedWindow but with slightly different functionality

Comment: @sbooth: I almost considered using your code, but unfortunately the detection of screen edges was rather flakey compared to MAAttachedWindow.  It would pop up the wrong way to be honest, even when set to automatic.

Comment: @sbooth: Actually, I just looked at it again and I was configuring it wrongly.  Switched to your code and I haven't looked back.  Thanks for sharing your awesome class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect situation to use [Heapshot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).

The symptoms you describe are exactly the same as the symptoms I saw in Hex Fiend when writing that article.

More likely than not, whatever is leaking -- and it really is a leak in that your app is accreting memory -- is still connected to the rest of the app's object graph.

Comment: Well, it looks like it's Matt Gemmell's code for `MAAttachedWindow` that is leaking.  Thanks for the tip, that'll come in handy.